# Android application move to sdcard option is disable

Tags: android, android-sdcard

The application I have made that does not have the option of move to SD card...

In my setting page I have no option for move app to sd card, but other application have it. Why is it like that? What is wrong I am doing?
[image]

And my application it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add property to your `manifest` Tag

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
....
android:installLocation="auto">
```

Answer (score 10):

The `Move to SD Card` option becomes disabled when you have

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

or if you have not set the `android:installLocation` explicitly in your manifest file.

According to [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

**By default, your application will be installed on the internal storage and cannot be installed on the external storage unless you define this attribute to be either "auto" or "preferExternal".**

Add

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

or

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

in your `<manifest>` tag